# How to properly create an item in a .bib file for a press bulletin?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I'm working with WriteLatex and want to create an item in my `.bib` file; so I add the following to the file

```
@misc{boletinDane2010,
    title ={Boletin de Prensa}
    author ={Departamento Administrativo Nacional Estadistico, DANE}
    year ={2014}
}
```

But I get the following error/warning and I don' understand why:

```
(no line number): 
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian) 
Capacity: max_strings=35307, hash_size=35307, hash_prime=30011 
The top-level auxiliary file: main.aux 
The style file: plain.bst 
Database file #1: bibliografia.bib.bib 
I was expecting a `,' or a `}'---line 17 of file bibliografia.bib.bib :
: author ={Departamento Administrativo Nacional Estadistico, DANE} 
(Error may have been on previous line) 
I'm skipping whatever remains of this entry 
Warning--to sort, need author or key in boletinDane2010 
You've used 1 entry, 
2118 wiz_defined-function locations, 
500 strings with 4044 characters, 
and the built_in function-call counts, 168 in all, are: 
= -- 12 
> -- 1 
< -- 0 
+ -- 1 
- -- 0 
* -- 7 
:= -- 23 
add.period$ -- 1 
call.type$ -- 1 
change.case$ -- 3 
chr.to.int$ -- 0 
cite$ -- 2 
duplicate$ -- 7 
empty$ -- 24 
format.name$ -- 0 
if$ -- 38 
int.to.chr$ -- 0 
int.to.str$ -- 1 
missing$ -- 0 
newline$ -- 6 
num.names$ -- 0 
pop$ -- 8 
preamble$ -- 1 
purify$ -- 2 
quote$ -- 0 
skip$ -- 10 
stack$ -- 0 
substring$ -- 5 
swap$ -- 1 
text.length$ -- 0 
text.prefix$ -- 0 
top$ -- 0 
type$ -- 4 
warning$ -- 1 
while$ -- 0 
width$ -- 2 
write$ -- 7 
(There was 1 error message)
```

My question then is: what am I doing wrong and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). Can you please add a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) so that people can see what packages etc you need to get your code to work (but don't add code that is not needed). Seeing a minimal version of your tex code makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: There's a second issue you should fix, in addition to providing the missing commas (already mentioned by @penguin in his/her answer). You should encase the contents of the `author` field should be encased in a second set of curly braces to indicate that it's a "corporate" author. Otherwise, poor BibTeX will interpret "DANE" as a first name, with unpredictable and probably undesired consequences. Hence, I'd write `author = {{Departamento Administrativo Nacional Estadistico, DANE}},`.

Comment: Good pick up @Mico. I just addressed the error message without looking at the content.

Answer (score 3):

You need to have commas at the end of each line:

```
@misc{boletinDane2010,
    title ={Boletin de Prensa},
    author ={Departamento Administrativo Nacional Estadistico, DANE},
    year ={2014},
}
```